# Analyse and cancel common frequency of wave file

Tags: python, matlab, audio, signal-processing, octave

I was working with audio processing but got stuck. I have a video file which first I converted to .wav file. Actually I need to extract only the vocal part. What I did is I am able to remove the vocal part and only the background sound. That means I have two file now one the main file another only the music file i.e. Karoake file. Both the file sample rate is same. What I am planning to do that to compare the file whenever the main file and karoake file at exactly the same time will give zero if both are same. In the process I can extract the vocal parts only.  I am new to octave and matlab. I am attaching my till date work.

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('music.wav');
[wave1,fs1]=wavread('sound.wav');
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
t1=0:1/fs1:(length(wave1)-1)/fs1;
for x=0:length(wave)
  if (wave{x}==wave1{x})
   wave2{x}=wave{x}-wave1{x};
else
  endif
endfor
```

for loop is showing an error.

**EDIT**: OK the question I asked was not actually the question. What I want is that to extract the vocal part only of an audio file.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: error: matrix cannot be indexed with {

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207376/vocal-of-an-audio-file
You don't need a for loop just calculate the difference: `wave2 = wave2 - wave;` This, of course, assumes that the sampling rate and length of music.wav and sound.wav are the same

Comment: btw, why is there a python tag if you want to do it in Octave?

Comment: yes but not the same question. this one is updated one..

Comment: @AtanuMandal you shouldn't create a new question for every little "update". The differences are minimal and you haven't even answered the questions in the comments of your previous question.

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab (or Octave) you can only index matrix with "()". Moreover the start index in Matlab is 1, not 0 like in C or Java. So I think your code must be correct by:

```
for x=1:length(wave)
  if (wave(x)==wave1(x))
   wave2(x)=wave(x)-wave1(x);
end
```

You can also remove the **for** instruction by using some arrays multiplications:

```
wave2 = (wave - wave1).*(wave1==wave);
```

Comment: perhaps you should rethink your last formula. Whats `wave - wave1` if `wave1==wave` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's equal to 0, but I just translate his **for** statement to matrix multiplication.

Comment: Ok I got your point But I need to extract the vocals. making the frequency 0 if both the files have same frequency at certain time. And result is not coming.

Comment: Can you explain me this one wave2 = (wave - wave1).*(wave1==wave);

Comment: `(wave1 == wave)` is an array with the same length as wave1 ( and wave) which contains only `0` and `1`. The element indexed by n is equals to `1` if `wave1(n) == wave(n)` else `0`. Moreover the element wise multiplication `.*` is using to do an multiplication element by element and not matrix multiplication. So this expression is an array equals to `0` if `wave1(n) != wave(n)` and equals to `wave(n) - wave1(n)` if `wave1(n) == wave(n)` (which is also '0' as noted Andy).

Comment: Any of the help didn't help my answer for extracting the vocals only from the audio file. It will be great if I get an answer .

Comment: Then if you want an answer for extracting the vocals, not for correcting your code then edit your comment and ask clearly what you're looking for.